# jqxdropdown select event calls multiple times?

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid, jqwidget

In JQWidgets, Inside JqxGrid control I had added jqxdropdown. Dropdown select event is call multiple times or ‘n’ number of items present into the list.

I had found below solution,
If argument is 'mouse' then only go for DB trip 
and its working for me ..

It may be helpful for you...

```
   $("#jqxgridPtr1").on('cellclick', function (event) {
        var args = event.args;
        ddlclicked = args.rowindex;
    });

    $("#jqxgridPtr1").on('select', function (event) {
        var args = event.args;
        if (args.type == 'mouse') {
            $("#jqxgridPtr1").jqxGrid('setcellvalue', ddlclicked, "IsMDRTotalComp", event.target.textContent);
            SavegridPtr1('1', ddlclicked);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are questioning or answering to the question?

Comment: I am giving solution if this type of question arise.

Comment: then why don't you add this in the answer area instead and you can accept it. That wil help you gain some points to do more things on SO.

Comment: Yeah!! thanks Jai.. I will go through it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $("#jqxgridPtr1").on('cellclick', function (event) {
        var args = event.args;
        ddlclicked = args.rowindex;
    });

    $("#jqxgridPtr1").on('select', function (event) {
        var args = event.args;
        if (args.type == 'mouse') {
            $("#jqxgridPtr1").jqxGrid('setcellvalue', ddlclicked, "IsMDRTotalComp", event.target.textContent);
            SavegridPtr1('1', ddlclicked);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you bind to jqxDropDownList event, you should select the jqxDropDownList's HTML Element, not the jqxGrid's HTML Element :)

Comment: jqxdropdown is inside the jqxgrid Here we need to do event bubbling. Otherwise your option is right. :)

Comment: The Grid itself uses many jqxDropDownLists so for example when you change the page size through the built-in DropDownList, using your approach your event handler will be called.